# What package provides -llua for g++?

Tags: package-management, gcc, shared-library, g++

I've installed all lua5.1 development packages from Synaptic and the g++ linker can not find `-llua`. I've read on some other question that it is possible that `-llua` has some other name and that I should fix it. But the problem is that I can't seem to find the `lua.o` or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc … -llua` looks for a file called `liblua.so` if you're linking dynamically (the default) or `liblua.a` if you're linking statically.

You can look for the package(s) containing a file by a certain name with [apt-file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt-file) [image: Install apt-file]. You can also make this search online on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents) (“Search the contents of package”, be sure to select your distribution and architecture). But…

```
$ apt-file search liblua.so
$
```

What's going on is that Ubuntu ships multiple versions of the Lua libraries, and they aren't binary compatible, i.e. you need to select the one you want at build time.

```
$ apt-file --regexp search '/liblua.*\.so$'
<lots of hits>
```

As of natty, the preferred version of Lua is [5.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/liblua5.1-0-dev), with [5.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/liblua50-dev) and [4.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/liblua40-dev) also available. The corresponding lua libraries for linking are `liblua5.1.so`, `liblua50.so` and `liblua40.so` (you can list the files in a package with `dpkg -L liblua5.1-0-dev` or `apt-file list liblua5.1-0-dev`). So you need to change your linking command to `-llua5.1` (or `-llua50` or `-llua40` if you need a binary that's compatible with older systems).